# Development versions management in private pypi repository

Tags: python, microservices, pypi, semantic-versioning, python-poetry

We are working on a product based on micro services and we are encountering some difficulties in the management of development versions of self-developed python packages shared between the components.

We would like to be able develop different features of the microservice alongside its dependencies, pulling separate development versions from our private pypi repository without interfering with stable releases.

#### Example

- utility package `XYZ` is shared across multiple services, currently at version `1.2.5`
- microservice `A` depends on `XYZ` version `^1.0.0`
- microservice `B` depends on `XYZ` version `^1.0.0`
- developer 1 is working on microservice `A` for feature `foo`
- developer 2 is working on microservice `B` for feature `bar`

##### Scenario

Both developers need to change XYZ to add core functionality that could be reused by other services in the future. Both developers branch from the current stable `1.2.5` version and start working on their features. At the end of the sprint, both of their branches will be merged and version `1.3.0` will be published.

In the meantime, during development, the developers want to be able to test the integration between the microservice they are working on and the package.

#### Problem

We use poetry to manage our dependencies, and we would like to use the private pypi repository to specify intervals of versions instead of hardcoding a tag or branch name when pulling from the private git repository directly.

We initially thought we could name our versions like in the example below, and make the microservice under development depend on this specific version

```
1.3.0-foo
1.3.0-bar
```

But we discovered that the PEP standard for version naming does not allow us to add custom labels to version.

Is there a best practice or workaround to keep working with our private pypi repository?

Comment: My first impression is that it is not possible, and I think that in such a case I would stick to using a specific branch of the git repository as source. -- Maybe the private package index allows [_`local version identifiers`_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#local-version-identifiers) and you can build some kind of work around, although I am not sure how that would work in practice. How would _pip_ resolve this if it is possible at all? -- If I were you I would ask [here](https://discuss.python.org/c/packaging/14) where the most knowledgeable people about such topics are active.

Comment: Maybe if you have good control of your whole tool chain, you can make it so that you create 1 project per branch (as long as the branch lives), for example: `XYZ-foo v1.3.0.dev9` and `XYZ-bar v1.3.0.dev12`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from the doc you should be able to specify a dev suffix like explained here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#examples-of-compliant-version-schemes

I'm looking at the section:

```
"major.minor" versioning with developmental releases, release candidates and post-releases for minor corrections:

0.9
1.0.dev1
1.0.dev2
1.0.dev3
1.0.dev4
```

What if dev 1 name his version as `1.3.dev1` and dev 2 as `1.3.dev2` and so on?

Comment: We ended up implementing a combination of this answer and @sinoroc 's comment. We now use a syntax like `1.2.3.dev+devname-12345678`, where `12345678` is a unix timestamp, in order to avoid conflicts on versions.